# get a JSON object from a string using AWS Lambda with EMR

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

So, in AWS EMR CLI, running the following commnand outputs a JSON like this (values are invalid now, so no fear of leaking sensitive info) :

[image]

Now in my Lambda python code, I want to extract the "state" value. Here's my code in python:

```
import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    jobid = event.get('jobID')
    url = '<public DNS of my EMR>/batches/' + str(jobid)
    res = requests.get(url)
    json_data = json.loads(res.text)
    return json_data.get('state')
```

I get an error like this:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'str' object has no attribute 'get'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 9, in lambda_handler\n    return json_data.get('state')\n"
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the **requests** module, you can use the `json()` method as explained [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to return the data as a JSON-like structure (dict).

So, you can do something like this:

```py
import requests
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    jobid = event.get('jobID')
    url = '<public DNS of my EMR>/batches/' + str(jobid)
    res = requests.get(url)
    js_res = res.json()
    return js_res['state']
```